# Gold badge for 1000 accepted answers

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

I recommend a gold badge for 1000 accepted answers posted by a single user. By this way, users would try to improve their answers by adding more explanations in-order to get his/her answers accepted.

Comment: Why only a gold badge? Should there be a silver and bronze too?

Comment: "...users would try to improve their answers by adding more explanations..." - Really? Because everyday I see more and more "Try this code" answers that are readily accepted without the first word of explanation.

Comment: @MikeM. Let us consider two answers. The one with brief explanation and the one with try this code answer.  Mostly the answer with some explanation which was so close to the op needs got accepted. And also i saw some users targeting on upvotes rather than accepts.

Comment: Actually, i've seen cases where the user accepts the simpler 'try this' answer, because it works, and no need to read through the whole explanation.

Comment: There's also the case of answers that contain a lot of fluff or non-explanation. There's nothing like reading through a long answer that contains irrelevant or wrong information.

Comment: There is a single user in the [tag:C] tag that keeps on posting long "fixed" code listings without any comment whatsoever. *Of course* this gets 'accepted', if only because it can be copied and pasted *verbatim* into the asker's e-mail to his professor .. `</cynicism>`. When pressed to add explanations, this person blandly stated that "the code speaks for itself". I gave up after commenting upon this a dozen times. Perhaps he's eligible for a lead badge.

Comment: Isn't the *accepted* mark *enough*? And it is upvotes over time that make you write better answers, not badges. And upvotes get you gold badges too, at 100 upvotes for your answer, plus the expert badges. Why have another reason for people to badger about accepting answers?

Answer (score 18):

Accepted answer doesn't indicate quality. Good answers get upvoted over time, and contribute towards the existing tag badges (gold, silver and bronze).

One should work on improving quality in order to make better contributions, which in the long run, get them upvotes and tag badges. They should NOT improve just for the sake of getting their answers accepted.

The **downside** of introducing the badge as per your suggestion is that users will start pushing askers to accept their answers. This will have the same negative impact on the community, which was earlier seen in the case of the "accept rate". Accept rate [had to be removed entirely](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136951/165773), and we don't need any other badge or factor which will again motivate users to bully askers.

I personally have flagged hundreds of such comments and conversations for moderators requesting them to purge entire threads of bullying, so by virtue of having witnessed it's impact, I know that this badge will be detrimental for the community, if introduced.

Comment: Why would this have any more of an incentive effect to nag users than the +15 for an accepted answer or the preferential placing? As you need 1,000 for the proposed badge I personally doubt it will have that effect.

Comment: @MartinSmith I guess the point is to avoid giving people a (yet another) "semi-official" justification for bullyiing. _Yeah I nagged asker to accept but that's because badge says getting your answer accepted is worth striving for..._

Comment: (humour) I fully support Avinash's proposal, provided we can earn that gold badge multiple times. I mean, I want 5 more gold badges now!

Comment: @VonC: Here are your badges ●●●●●